# two ViewPagers synchronized scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I need to synchronize scrolling in two viewpagers.

Here some relevant code:

```
super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        mViewPager.fakeDragBy(mViewPager.getScrollX()-getScrollX());
        return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return mViewPager.onTouchEvent(ev);
```

I`m getting touch event, and scrolling the second view by the same amount. But one thing I can't manage is to disable or handle fling similarly, I mean short fast gestrue which automaticaly makes scroll jump to next page.

Structure is
-ViewPagerNavigator-
-ViewPagerMenu-

How do I make fling in it to work on menu pager, or just disable it?

Comment: I'm not sure it'll make a difference, but have you played around with the [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface? In stead of capturing the touch event directly, I imagine you could use the `onPageScrolled(...)` method and the passed in offset. For flings you might be able to get away with `onPageSelected(...)`.

Comment: good point, very good point, seems it is working, i just now need to load layout from adapter, thanks, post it as answer and I`ll accept it.

Comment: please check my answer here. I think I'm using a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26513243/2008214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per earlier commment:

I'm not sure it'll make a difference, but have you played around with the [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface? In stead of capturing the touch event directly, I imagine you could use the `onPageScrolled(...)` method and the passed in offset. For flings you might be able to get away with `onPageSelected(...)`.

Comment: you can check my answer here, based on what you are saying: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26513243/2008214

Answer (score 0):

You can Check Out my answer here

[Synchronizing two ViewPagers using OnPageChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107016/synchronizing-two-viewpagers-using-onpagechangelistener/24104748#24104748)

You can also set different PageTransformers on these as well.