# Synchronizing two ViewPagers using OnPageChangeListener

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to synchronize two `ViewPager`s, as apparently have quite a lot of people before me, and I've got as far as this:

```
private ViewPager mNavPager;

private ViewPager mMainPager;

private final OnPageChangeListener mNavPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    private boolean mNavDragging;
    private int mScrollPosition;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mScrollPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(mNavDragging)
            mMainPager.scrollTo(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        switch(state) {
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            mNavDragging = true;
            break;
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            mNavDragging = false;
            break;
        }
    }
};

private OnPageChangeListener mMainPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    private boolean mMainDragging;
    private int mScrollPosition;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mScrollPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(mMainDragging)
            mNavPager.scrollTo(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        switch(state) {
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            mMainDragging = true;
            break;
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            mMainDragging = false;
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

If either one is scrolled manually, the other is slaved to it using the scroll state property.  It works beautifully till the items reach their final position; at this point, the slaved pager flicks instantly back to the previously selected item, as though the scrolling hadn't taken place.

I have tried calling `ViewPager#setCurrentItem(mScrolledPosition)` with a variety of different logic constraints but that doesn't work either, though it does occasionally make it worse.  I feel as though there must be something that can be done with that but I'm not sure what.

How can I get the slaved pager to remain in the correct position?

Answer (score 20):

I solved this problem in a much easier (and cleaner) way using the OnPageChangeListener:

```
mViewPager1.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

      private int mScrollState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          return;
        }
        mViewPager2.scrollTo(mViewPager1.getScrollX(), mViewPager2.getScrollY());
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
        mScrollState = state;
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(mViewPager1.getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
      }
});

mViewPager2.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

      private int mScrollState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          return;
        }
        mViewPager1.scrollTo(mViewPager2.getScrollX(), mViewPager1.getScrollY());
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
        mScrollState = state;
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          mViewPager1.setCurrentItem(mViewPager2.getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: I tried something like this and found it only worked partially: slight differences in timing caused the velocity of the slaved pager to overshoot or undershoot occasionally.

Comment: So far I never had problems. Everything works smoothly.

Comment: You should change the current item on `onPageScrollStateChanged()` when the `state` is `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` also. That's when Android does it.

Comment: Actually, some flicking occurs setting the current item when the scroll flag is `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` also. But if I don't, I don't get the flicking but the tabs might not load fast enough. I believe these issues will only occur for heavy tabs with images and such.

Answer (score 7):

I have Solved the problem without utilizing the Listener.
So you can use the listener for some other stuff and will make code look cleaner.

I know its a question asked a long ago. I was searching for a solution and solved it myself.

This is how my Custom ViewPager code is

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {
CustomPager mCustomPager;
private boolean forSuper;

public CustomPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    if (!forSuper) {

        mCustomPager.forSuper(true);
        mCustomPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
        mCustomPager.forSuper(false);
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    if (!forSuper) {
        mCustomPager.forSuper(true);
        mCustomPager.onTouchEvent(arg0);
        mCustomPager.forSuper(false);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
}

public void setViewPager(CustomPager customPager) {
    mCustomPager = customPager;
}

public void forSuper(boolean forSuper) {
    this.forSuper = forSuper;
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    if (!forSuper) {
        mCustomPager.forSuper(true);
        mCustomPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
        mCustomPager.forSuper(false);
    }
    super.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
    if (!forSuper) {
        mCustomPager.forSuper(true);
        mCustomPager.setCurrentItem(item);
        mCustomPager.forSuper(false);
    }
    super.setCurrentItem(item);

}

}
```

And you have to set pagers like this before adapter is set and just after getting reference using the ID.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    backPager=(CustomPager) findViewById(R.id.BackPager);
    frontPager = (CustomPager) findViewById(R.id.frontPager);
    frontPager.setViewPager(backPager);
    backPager.setViewPager(frontPager);
    backPager.setAdapter(your Adapter);
    frontPager.setAdapter(your Adapter);
}
```

Must set ViewPagers before assigning adapter.

Comment: This looks similar to something I tried—I'll have a go with this, thank you!

Comment: I am using it in my application. What are your thoughts on it.
Is it working correctly for you?

Comment: @Andrew Wyld I am trying to achieve same viewpager thing. Do had any success in this?

Comment: This solution will crash if you touch both viewpagers at the same time.

Comment: Works flawlessly. @minivac I don't get any crash when touching and scrolling both pagers.

Comment: Only this solution can work with viewpager-transformer-animation.

Comment: thanks to you...this concept saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, also needed to combine my syncing with animations in `PageTransformer`.

Originally posted this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638796/2867886

But I will paste it here for convenience.

The solution that worked best for me was to pass `MotionEvent` in `OnTouchListener` between `ViewPager` instances. Tried fake dragging but it was always laggy and buggy - I needed a smooth, parallax-like effect.

So, my advice is to implement a `View.OnTouchListener`. The `MotionEvent` has to be scaled to compensate for the difference in width.

```
public class SyncScrollOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final View syncedView;

public SyncScrollOnTouchListener(@NonNull View syncedView) {
    this.syncedView = syncedView;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    MotionEvent syncEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
    float width1 = view.getWidth();
    float width2 = syncedView.getWidth();

    //sync motion of two view pagers by simulating a touch event
    //offset by its X position, and scaled by width ratio
    syncEvent.setLocation(syncedView.getX() + motionEvent.getX() * width2 / width1,
            motionEvent.getY());
    syncedView.onTouchEvent(syncEvent);
    return false;
}
}
```

Then set it to your `ViewPager`

```
    sourcePager.setOnTouchListener(new SyncScrollOnTouchListener(targetPager));
```

Note that this solution will only work if both pagers have the same orientation. If you need it to work for different orientations - adjust `syncEvent` Y coordinate instead of X.

There is one more issue that we need to take into account - minimum fling speed and distance that can cause just one pager to change page.

It can be easily fixed by adding an `OnPageChangeListener` to our pager

```
sourcePager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //no-op
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            targetPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //no-op
        }
    });
```

Comment: awesome! thank you! :) and a lot more beatiful than the solution with the OnPageChangeListener

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thanks a lot, works great!

Answer (score 2):

This does everything right *except* it sometimes misses very quick flicks on the slaved view.  For some reason including fake drag events during the settling phase causes real problems, though.

```
private ViewPager mNavPager;

private ViewPager mMainPager;

private final OnPageChangeListener mNavPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    private int mLastScrollPosition;
    private int mLastPagePosition;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mLastPagePosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(mMainPager.isFakeDragging()) {
            int absoluteOffsetPixels = positionOffsetPixels;
            if(mLastPagePosition!=position) {
                absoluteOffsetPixels += (position - mLastPagePosition) * mMainPager.getWidth();
                mLastPagePosition = position;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "fake nav drag by " + (mLastScrollPosition - absoluteOffsetPixels));
            mMainPager.fakeDragBy(mLastScrollPosition - absoluteOffsetPixels);
            mLastScrollPosition = positionOffsetPixels;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if(!mNavPager.isFakeDragging()) {
            switch(state) {
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                if(!mMainPager.isFakeDragging())
                    mMainPager.beginFakeDrag();
                break;
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(mMainPager.isFakeDragging()) {
                    mMainPager.endFakeDrag();
                    mLastScrollPosition = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

private OnPageChangeListener mMainPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    private int mLastScrollPosition;
    private int mLastPagePosition;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mLastPagePosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(mNavPager.isFakeDragging()) {
            int absoluteOffsetPixels = positionOffsetPixels;
            if(mLastPagePosition!=position) {
                absoluteOffsetPixels += (position - mLastPagePosition) * mMainPager.getWidth();
                mLastPagePosition = position;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "fake nav drag by " + (mLastScrollPosition - absoluteOffsetPixels));
            mNavPager.fakeDragBy(mLastScrollPosition - absoluteOffsetPixels);
            mLastScrollPosition = positionOffsetPixels;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if(!mMainPager.isFakeDragging()) {
            switch(state) {
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                if(!mNavPager.isFakeDragging())
                    mNavPager.beginFakeDrag();
                break;
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(mNavPager.isFakeDragging()) {
                    mNavPager.endFakeDrag();
                    mLastScrollPosition = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

I now believe this to be impossible without some fairly substantial custom code.  The reason is essentially that both `ViewPager`s have a `VelocityTracker` inside, which controls scrolling.  Since the `MotionEvent`s being passed in may not be passed to the `VelocityTracker` at the same relative times for each pager, the trackers will occasionally reach different conclusions about how to react.

However, it *is* possible to use a modified `PagerTitleStrip` to get precise tracking of a `ViewPager`, and to transfer touch events captured by the strip directly to the `ViewPager`.

[The source for `PagerTitleStrip` is here.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.java)

Broadly, what needs to be done to make this work is as follows: replace `mPrevText`, `mCurrText` and `mNextText` with views of the type you want to use; remove the `onAttachedToWindow()` and `onDetachedFromWindow()` functions; remove calls to the `PagerAdapter` that deal with dataset observers, and add an `OnTouchListener` to the modified strip that fake drags the main pager.  You'll also need to add the modified title strip as an `OnPageChangeListener` to the `ViewPager` since the internal listeners aren't visible outside the package.

Is this a gigantic pain?  Yes.  But it works.  I will write it up in more detail soon.

Comment: Did you end up writing it in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

With help from all other answers I've created a Class so it easily can be implemented.

```
    public class OnPageChangeListernerSync implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager master;
    private ViewPager slave;
    private int mScrollState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

    public OnPageChangeListernerSync(ViewPager master, ViewPager slave){
        this.master = master;
        this.slave = slave;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            return;
        }
        this.slave.scrollTo(this.master.getScrollX()*
                this.slave.getWidth()/
                this.master.getWidth(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
        mScrollState = state;
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            this.slave.setCurrentItem(this.master
                    .getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
// In your activity
this.upperPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListernerSync(this.upperPager, this.lowerPager));

this.lowerPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListernerSync(this.lowerPager, this.upperPager));
```

Answer (score 0):

All the Answers are approximately currect in some situation. Here I am giving one more answer which will use to **slide both the ViewPagers simultaneously whether there size is same or not**:

```
viewPagerBanner.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    private int scrollState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
    // Indicates that the pager is in an idle, settled state. 
    // The current page is fully in view and no animation is in progress.

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
                               int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (scrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            return;
        }
        viewPagerTitle.scrollTo(viewPagerBanner.getScrollX()*
                                viewPagerTitle.getWidth()/
                                viewPagerBanner.getWidth(), 0);
        // We are not interested in Y axis position
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        scrollState = state;
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            viewPagerTitle.setCurrentItem(viewPagerBanner.getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
    }
});
```