# Android 2 ViewPagers simultanious scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is it possible to have 2 `ViewPagers` that simultaniously scroll together, if I start scrolling on one, the other does the exact same scrolling behaviour. Or should I implement somthing other than a ViewPager.

thank you

Comment: paste your layout xml code

Comment: I don't have it yet, I'm still researching a way to do it, thank you

Comment: use OnPageChangeListener  in first fragment and sync it with second ViewPager.

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked best for me was to pass `MotionEvent` in `OnTouchListener` between `ViewPager` instances. Tried fake dragging but it was always laggy and buggy (tried the solution from this thread too - didn't work) - I needed a smooth, parallax-like effect.

So, my advice is to implement a `View.OnTouchListener`. The `MotionEvent` has to be scaled to compensate for the difference in width.

```
public class SyncScrollOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private final View syncedView;

public SyncScrollOnTouchListener(@NonNull View syncedView) {
    this.syncedView = syncedView;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    MotionEvent syncEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
    float width1 = view.getWidth();
    float width2 = syncedView.getWidth();

    //sync motion of two view pagers by simulating a touch event
    //offset by its X position, and scaled by width ratio
    syncEvent.setLocation(syncedView.getX() + motionEvent.getX() * width2 / width1,
            motionEvent.getY());
    syncedView.onTouchEvent(syncEvent);
    return false;
}
}
```

Then set it to your `ViewPager`

```
    sourcePager.setOnTouchListener(new SyncScrollOnTouchListener(targetPager));
```

Note that this solution will only work if both pagers have the same orientation. If you need it to work for different orientations - adjust `syncEvent` Y coordinate instead of X.

There is one more issue that we need to take into account - minimum fling speed and distance that can cause just one pager to change page.

It can be easily fixed by adding an `OnPageChangeListener` to our pager

```
sourcePager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
            //no-op
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            targetPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //no-op
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give each an `OnPageChangeListsner` and implement `onPageScrolled` (and maybe also `onPageSelected` for when you change pages without scrolling). Since the logic will be the same, we can write a class for this:

```
public class ViewPagerScrollSync implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private ViewPager actor; // the one being scrolled
    private ViewPager target; // the one that needs to be scrolled in sync

    public ViewPagerScrollSync(ViewPager actor, ViewPager target) {
        this.actor = actor;
        this.target = target;
        actor.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if (actor.isFakeDragging()) {
            return;
        }

        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            // actor has begun a drag
            target.beginFakeDrag();
        } else if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // actor has finished settling
            target.endFakeDrag();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (actor.isFakeDragging()) {
            return;
        }
        if (target.isFakeDragging()) {
            // calculate drag amount in pixels.
            // i don't have code for this off the top of my head, but you'll probably
            // have to store the last position and offset from the previous call to
            // this method and take the difference.
            float dx = ...
            target.fakeDragBy(dx);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (actor.isFakeDragging()) {
            return;
        }

        // Check isFakeDragging here because this callback also occurs when
        // the user lifts his finger on a drag. If it was a real drag, we will
        // have begun a fake drag of the target; otherwise it was probably a
        // programmatic change of the current page.
        if (!target.isFakeDragging()) {
            target.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity/Fragment, you would do this:

```
ViewPager pager1 = ...
ViewPager pager2 = ...
ViewPagerScrollSync sync1 = new ViewPagerScrollSync(pager1, pager2);
ViewPagerScrollSync sync2 = new ViewPagerScrollSync(pager2, pager1);
```

Comment: I've added some checks for `actor.isFakeDragging()` to prevent cyclical callbacks. You should try it out and see if they're necessary or not.

Comment: Did you guys really succeed using this? I've tried it, but it keeps getting out of sync between the viewPagers.

Comment: Nice, elegant solution. Two things to add: one is that I got this working when using `target.isFakeDragging` instead of `!target.isFakeDragging` in `onPageScrolled`; the other is that the `onPageScrolled` method seems to get called while the fake drag is still in place for the `target`. This causes the `target` to switch the right position, but then switch back to the position it started from (if "forward scrolling") as soon as the drag is ended.

Comment: In order to circumvent the last issue, I've added an `endFakeDrag` and `setCurrentItem` for the `actor`, in `onPageSelected` when the actor is fake dragging and added a `target.isFakeDragging` check in `onPageScrollStateChanged` so that `endFakeDrag` isn't called when not fake dragging.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to keep an eye on your positions to avoid `IndexOutOfBounds` errors. Generally:

```
        viewPager1.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            viewPager2.setCurrentItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

This will work assuming that both `ViewPagers` have the same number of items. Otherwise, you will need to track your positions to synchronize the behavior of both pagers.

To clarify: if your `Adapters` have a different number of items or you don't want both pagers to behave exactly the same, you will need to check the position of `viewPager1` in the `onPageSelected()` method and then adjust the position to pass to the `setCurrentItem()` method of `viewPager2`

Comment: wouldn't this only triger when a page is selected, I want something like when I start scrolling, the other view starts also, so it's kinda looks like a mirroring effect

Comment: this is all possible with the `OnPageChangeListener`. Please consult the docs regarding this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Drop this class in your project

```
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
/**
 * Sync Scroll 2 View Pager
 */
public class SyncScrollOnTouchListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager master;
    private ViewPager slave;
    private int mScrollState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

    public SyncScrollOnTouchListener(ViewPager master, ViewPager slave){
        this.master = master;
        this.slave = slave;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            return;
        }
        this.slave.scrollTo(this.master.getScrollX()*
                this.slave.getWidth()/
                this.master.getWidth(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
        mScrollState = state;
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            this.slave.setCurrentItem(this.master
                    .getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

Now you can sync page change of View Pages

> **masterPager**.addOnPageChangeListener(newSyncScrollOnTouchListener(**masterPager**,slavePager));

```
    //Sync Scroll of Pages
  
    leftPanelPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SyncScrollOnTouchListener(leftPanelPager,rightPanelPager));
    rightPanelPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SyncScrollOnTouchListener(rightPanelPager,leftPanelPager));
```